# How to drag and drop an image out of Electron on Next.js?

Tags: next.js, electron, drag-and-drop

I'm struggling to get drag & drop functionality to run in Electron when it wraps Next.js. I follow an official Electron [tutorial](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/native-file-drag-drop) on d&d and base my code on an [example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-electron-typescript) in the official Next.js repo. I was able to get d&d working in a quick start Electron app after following the steps described in an official example.

The issue I'm having is that when I drag a file outside of an Electron application to Finder, only a `.fileloc` or `.webloc` file is being dragged, not the file I send with `sendDrag`.

I'm not sure why is it happening. Could it be that d&d out of Electron is supported only when the browser window loads a file with `loadFile`, not a url with `loadURL`? In that case, I'm not sure how can I run exported html Next.js files without a server...

Answer (score 0):

Alright, turned out I forgot to add `event.preventDefault()`. This is the commit with the fix https://github.com/cbrwizard/nexj.js-with-electron-typescript/commit/e3fba369287c7506263c36db36ada0c61246808b#diff-5a46010a5570ab7e32855454c53ccc06bd1f7b08e2099db4ff3a3f0c584e3f05R31